# Is there an easy way to create a fixture in Django without using dump_data?

Tags: django

Is there an easy way to create fixtures, without using dump_data?  We have a complex database and it seems like creating the fixtures directly, without using dump_data would mean a lot of work.

Can I create objects and write them to json so they can be used as fixtures?

Note that we are using multiple applications and data is referenced between applications.

Comment: Couldn't understand your problem. Why not just create an objects and dump_data? So dump_data a lot of work? Usually I create Factory objects for testing purposes `FactoryBoy`.

Comment: What if I need 1000 or even 100 objects?  The database is quite complex.  Also part of the data is created using another software. I am exploring creating the data without that software.

Comment: can you just write a simple script to loop the creation?

Answer (score 2):

I've used [Django Dynamic Fixtures](https://github.com/paulocheque/django-dynamic-fixture) for several years and found it really great. It generates fixtures based on your model definitions.

If you have a model `Project` you can generate your fixtures in a test environment using the command `G(Project)` and optionally customize it with `G(Project, name='test')` etc.

```
from django_dynamic_fixture import G
from apps.projects.models import Project

class TestProject(TestCase):
    """
    Test project name
    """
    def setUp(self):
        self.project1 = G(Project)
        self.project2 = G(Project, name="my project")

    def test_project(self):
        self.assertTrue(self.project1)

    def test_name(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.project2.name, "my project")
```

Comment: Wouldn't I need to first create instances of the model, i.e., somehow populate data and then use G(Blog)?

Comment: no - it auto-populates an instance using the model definition. I've added a more detailed example

Comment: linked to github in answer - here are the docs: http://django-dynamic-fixture.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: where is the detailed example?  How is the auto-population done, is it random strings and numbers?

Comment: Yes, it randomly generates all content based on your database fields. Did you look at the docs? They are very comprehensive

Answer (score 0):

How about using serializers of DRF? (or any library that you are familiar with)

You can serialize objects to json easily using DRF.

Just output them to file.

Comment: I am not sure of the data format required to load the data, i.e., of the fixture file, especially for a complex database.  I am not sure if I can just serialize and then load the data.

Comment: Based on my experience, the way you can load the fixture file isn't that flexible. So I had trouble dumping the data the way I want. I think DRF is a fantastic tool to serialize data to format that django will understand to load later.